# "Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?" does not disappear immediately

Tags: bug, comments, chat

[I automatically moved a conversation on PPCG to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58225/discussion-between-meq5anlrk3lqs3kfsa5hbvstwe0niu-and-adam) and the box still showed up **for more than a hour**, making it seem like I could move the conversation to chat a second time. Out of fear this would create *another* chat room I didn't click it, so I don't know if it would error out, but the box should probably disappear immediately.

As I noticed I immediately switched to this site and by mistake closed my browser tab with the original question. After reloading the box finally disappeared, but that means I can't attach screenshots. Hopefully this is enough to reproduce...?

Immediate edit: The box showed up again.
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: During that first hour when you noticed the box sticking around, did you ever refresh the page during that time?

Comment: I believe so, but can't 100% confirm (habit of keeping tabs open). Regardless, the box showed up after a reload again right after I posted the question, hence the edit.

Comment: Actually, the box is *still* showing up...

Answer (score 2):

Rebooting my computer, refreshing the tab multiple times, and closing and reopening the tab doesn't work either. The message still persists.

[image]

Link: [Move two matches so that no triangle remains](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/116764/move-two-matches-so-that-no-triangle-remains/)